# Can a user ask about having their account suspended for a certain period?

Tags: support, accounts, account-suspension

I know that's a quite unusual question, but as I was asked about that offsite, I'll present it here.

My friend wants to get blocked at SO for a certain period, so he's able to concentrate on his real work and not be tempted to appear here.

Is that possible? Could he ask about that at the contact us link?

Comment: This has been asked before, I'm sure, but I can't now find it. The answer was no, IIRC; SO isn't your (friend's) conscience.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker great find, and the first comment is by...!

Comment: @jon LOL. Alzheimer :-P

Comment: Perhaps s/he would be interested in purchasing an existing suspension from a 3rd-party?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I already recommended him simply to take on trust in his discipline.

Comment: Use he could redirect SO to a custom html page, with a motivational talk on it..

Comment: This question could be a cross site duplicate on [Parenting SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/), "How to stop my kid from going to Website?".

Comment: "asking for a friend" ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, I was doing so. I don't consider that for myself. Any problems with that?

Comment: I was kidding! Sorry, no offense meant.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I well know how that sounds, but I'm not a 1 rep newbie, ya know ;-).